# friends locator

Tags: c#, .net, open-source, gps

i want an program in .net . as an mobile application .in which by using gps system we can locate the position of an person within the mobile application group ,with his/her authority.
so i need guidence please.

Comment: goood luck ..... by the way what is locator ?

Comment: i have to make an mobile application in which i can make a friends group. and i can locate our group members on the map using gps.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms881362.aspx) sample for more information on your GPS location. I'd say: store and update the GPS location on a central server and refer to that central server for the GPS locations of your friends.